# Recently received a odd email

Tags: email

```
http://photomi.co.kr/httpcnbc9home-2.com.php?subpage216
Learn How to Make Money 0nline Fast




__________________
. louanne visszakuldod
Sun, 22 Jul 2012 0:33:42
```

Is there a way to identify what this page that is being linked to it doing? I'm afraid to click the link due to the odd site and spelling Online with a zero.

Comment: Typical scam. It takes you to a fake cnbc website with an article modified by your ip geo about someone who makes X dollars a month; all links go onto another website with a form asking for personal information. It will probably then try and get you to install some software. Unfortunately I didn't see anything special but I could of missed something. Take Terry Chia's advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree that in these situations you should not click the link.  I know you're curious, but you don't really need to know what badness will actually happen if you click on the link to know that clicking on the link probably isn't a great idea.

That said, one tool for analyzing dubious web pages is [Wepawet](http://wepawet.iseclab.org/index.php).  You can view [Wepawet's report on that web page](http://wepawet.iseclab.org/view.php?hash=085eb555e37fe91b27860de46070504f&t=1343108573&type=js); Wepawet does not detect any drive-by downloads, but it classifies the web page as "suspicious" and notes that the page redirects to `http://cnbc9home.com/` (which is also a bit suspicious).  You can also view [Wepawet's report on that domain](http://wepawet.iseclab.org/domain.php?hash=7cecd126c4d0ff777099012abbc698a4&type=js), which identifies that the page links to a variety of sketchy-sounding web sites (rxpharmacyclub.net, pillrxmedsguide.com, makemoneyonline14.ru, and more like that -- these are not the characteristics of a legitimate site).  So, from Wepawet's report, it becomes pretty clear that this is a pretty dubious site, even if Wepawet does not identify all of the bad stuff the page does.

But again, you don't need to go into all this detail to know not to click on the link.

Answer (score 9):

It will most likely infect your computer with some malware or keylogger.

Use a VM or a computer you are willing to reformat after to access the link, and run some malware analysis tool to check out what is happening.

If you have to ask here though, I suggest you just ignore the link. Malware analysis is a very complex topic that is difficult to understand.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. When browsing to the link malware bytes firewall blocks the connection from the website. Connection is not established with the site. I'm assuming that considering malware bytes knows about it, that it for sure is not safe.  Thanks!

Comment: @Fogest - Malwarebyte blocks access to host based on past reports.  Mutliple websites could be placed on the same host, some could be perfectly safe, others hostile.  Of course in this case the website at the very best is a spam website.

Comment: Claiming the malware author "most likely" knows a code-execution vulnerability against the browser or a plugin is a bold claim. It's sometimes true, but in that case doing almost anything using the browser is a risk.

Comment: @ComputerLocus Browsing to the link was a very dangerous move, but thankfully it looks like Malware Bytes protected you.  Now we know the link is even more likely (almost certainly) malicious.  Like I say, as a general rule, don't click on links in e-mail (unless it was "expected", such as asking a friend to send you the link to a website).

Answer (score 0):

Definitely a scam, so don't even bother trying to click the link. It will most likely take over your computer and either wipe your data, or install malware that will become active soon. If you want a secure way to communicate (without spam, phishing or data mining) try Ziptr. Everything is encrypted end to end.

Comment: Can a webpage actually do this though without requiring some message to pop up asking for permission to download something?

Comment: @Fogest Only if it manages to exploit a security hole in your browser.

Comment: @CodesInChaos which I'd assume Google Chrome does not have many known ones for. But I guess better to be safe then sorry.

Comment: @Fogest Even Google Chrome is not immune to vulnerabilities (there have been some that have been discovered and patched).  That is why it is important to keep your software up to date.

Comment: @Jonathan I honestly have no idea why you keep coming back to this question. You made an answer on Oct 31st and you are back later with a comment. The question is resolved and has a approved answer. This question is done. And your answer doesn't even add anything new. The stuff has already been said.

Answer (score -1):

It is generally good security practice not to click on links from e-mails from people you don't know (and often times even from people you do know if you don't really need to visit the link), as they can link to malicious sites.  These sites can load malware onto your computer, or can trick you into revealing personal information.  This link almost certainly links to a malicious site, as seen in the other answers provided.

Here is an example I found on this site where someone went through the effort to trace out a malicious link, and you may find it informative if you so choose to research the malicious link further (which I would do with extreme caution as the other answers show):

[how to back track a phishing attach? (without being infected)](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/72315/how-to-back-track-a-phishing-attach-without-being-infected)